# response.json was not working, now python is being funky

Tags: python, json, api

No matter what I tried, JSON, being a jerk, was not working. See code:

```py
import requests 
import response as response 
from pandas.io.formats import console class DataManager:     
# This class is responsible for talking to the Google Sheet.     
url = 'https://api.sheety.co/63978dbae6cae43f2cccf3e22fda65ce/myFlightDeals/prices';     
response = response.json     
pass
```

So then I tried updating the version, created a different problem. This problem: 5:28 PM Installing packages failed: Installing packages: error occurred. Details…

Comment: I see a *lot* of things wrong with this code sample; I don’t know where to start.

Comment: Also I searched on pypi and found [this](https://pypi.org/project/response/) library, but I think it doesn’t do what you might want. So to start with, I don’t understand where the `import response` is coming from.

Comment: rv.kvetch - It's coming from a course in python I'm doing on udemy. The instructor told me to put it there so I did, It worked in the past so I thought it would work here.

Comment: These are the instructions.    Make requests using the Sheety API
2. Now use the Sheety API to GET all the data in that sheet and print it out. You should see something like this:


3. Try importing pretty print with the line from pprint import pprint and printing the data out again using pprint() to see it formatted.

4. Pass everything stored in the "prices" key back to the main.py file and store it in a variable called sheet_data, so that you can print the sheet_data from main.py

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that should work. I'm still not clear on what the `import response` is for, but to make an HTTP request to a url and retrieve a response, you will need to use the `requests` library like this. Note that you can similarly also make other requests based on HTTP verbs if your endpoint supports it, like GET, PUT, POST, and HEAD.

```py
import requests


url = 'https://api.sheety.co/63978dbae6cae43f2cccf3e22fda65ce/myFlightDeals/prices';

r = requests.get(url)

# in case you need to confirm request was a success (200 status)
# r.raise_for_status()

print(r.json())
# prints:
# {'errors': [{'detail': 'invalid_grant'}]}

# access error message, in case the request was invalid
err_msg: str = r.json()['errors'][0]['detail']
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I was able to get it working based on your approach